# Saving a string found with .contains as a String variable?

Tags: string, java.util.scanner, contains

First of all, I don't have any code to show yet, but the idea is that there is a text document that contains information, say... 'John Fitzgerald New York' on a single line, and I want to find that via `.contains()`, for example:

```
Scanner newScanner = new Scanner(inputFile);

String name = "Fitzgerald";

while(!newScanner.nextLine().contains(name)){

}
```

The idea being that I can then save the entire line as a variable. A search for Fitzgerald should allow me to save John Fitzgerald New York as a variable, in other words. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt")); // Read from file
final String pattern = "Fitzgerald"
while( sc.hasNext() ){ // While you still have more data
    String l = sc.next(); // Get the next token
    if( l.contains(pattern) ){ // Check if it matches your pattern
        System.out.println("Match Found");
    }
}
```

This is how you would do it if you want to loop over the tokens. Alternatively, you can use the `next(Pattern)` method if you want to find more complex patterns.

For a text document, consider using a `FileReader`.

```
final String pattern = "Fitzgerald"
FileReader f = new FileReader(new File("input.txt"));
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
String line;
while( (line=b.readLine()) != null ){
    if(line.contains(pattern)){
        doSomething(line);
    }
}
```